# How can I prnt scrn to USB drive in bash linux

Tags: linux, bash

During early stages of installing linux, when in the bash terminal is it possible to screen capture and save the output to a mounted USB drive?

Comment: Take a look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202391/bash-script-to-take-screenshot-and-save-the-image-ubuntu

Comment: What distro? Most modern distros either use a curses based installer or a fully graphical one. What sort of information, specifically, are you after?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Gentoo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `fbgrab`?

Usage: `fbgrab [options] filename`

So if your USB drive is mounted at `/mount/flashdrive`, you could try `fbgrab /mount/flashdrive/screenshot0.png`.